# Left join two R data frames with OR conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr

### Problem

I have two data frames that I want to join using a conditional statement on three non-numeric variables. Here is a pseudo-code version of what I want to achieve.

```
Join DF1 and DF2 on DF1$A == DF2$A | DF1$A == DF2$B
```

### Dataset

Here's some code to create the two data frames. `variant_index` is the data frame that will be used to annotate `input` using a `left_join`:

```
library(dplyr)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

set.seed(5)
variant_index <- data.frame(
  rsid   = rep(sapply(1:5, function(x) paste0(c("rs", sample(0:9, 8, replace = TRUE)), collapse = "")), each = 2),
  chrom  = rep(sample(1:22, 5), each = 2),
  ref    = rep(sample(c("A", "T", "C", "G"), 5, replace = TRUE), each = 2),
  alt    = sample(c("A", "T", "C", "G"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  eaf    = runif(10),
  stringAsFactors = FALSE
)
variant_index[1, "alt"] <- "T"
variant_index[8, "alt"] <- "A"

input <- variant_index[seq(1, 10, 2), ] %>%
  select(rsid, chrom)
input$assessed <- c("G", "C", "T", "A", "T")
```

### What I tried

I would like to perform a `left_join` on `input` to annotate with the `eaf` column from `variant_index`. As you can see from the `input` data frame, its `assessed` column can match either with `input$ref` or with `input$alt`. The `rsid` and `chrom` column will always match.

I know I can specify multiple column in the `by` argument of `left_join`, but if I understand correctly, the condition will always be

```
input$assessed == variant_index$ref & input$assessed == variant_index$alt
```

whereas I want to achieve

```
input$assessed == variant_index$ref | input$assessed == variant_index$alt
```

### Possible solution

The desired output can be obtained like so:

```
input %>% 
  left_join(variant_index) %>% 
  filter(assessed == ref | assessed == alt)
```

But it doesn't seem like the best solution to me, since I am possibly generating double the lines, and would like to apply this join to data frames containing 100M+ lines. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex joins are straight forward in SQL:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select *
  from variant_index v
  join input i on i.assessed = v.ref or i.assessed = v.alt")
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it impossible using `dplyr` then? I'm totally fine with `sqldf`, but for consistency I was looking to use only `dplyr`.

Comment: dplyr does not support general joins directly.  You could put `sqldf` in your pipeline.  `input %>% { sqldf("select *
  from variant_index v 
  join [.] i on i.assessed = v.ref or i.assessed = v.alt") }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
library(dbplyr) 
x1 <- memdb_frame(x = 1:5) 
x2 <- memdb_frame(x1 = 1:3,x2 = letters[1:3]) 
x1 <- x1 %>% left_join(b, sql_on = "a.x=b.x1 or a.x=b.x2")
```

we can use show_query to see the code